# Text align: center on list item block

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I've created simple responsive navigation menu with media queries. I faced the weird situation. After applying `text-align:center` to center text in blocks, the first `li` element is moved slightly to left, others are centered fine. I can't figure out what's the issue. I tried `margin: 0 auto`, it doesn't work for me. 
This is what's happening:
[image: menu image]

Here's the code:

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="menu" role="button">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>blog</li>
      <li>team</li>
      <li>contact</li>  
    </ul>
  </nav>   
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
  background:grey;
  .logo{
    font-size:40px;
    color:white;
    background:blue;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .menu{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
  }
  nav{
    display:inline-block;
    ul{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      li{
      display:inline-block;
      margin: 0 20px;
      background:orange; 
      }
    }
  }
}
@media screen and(max-width:600px){
  header{
    .menu{
      display:inline-block;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      margin:10px;
      span{
        border-top: 5px solid #fff;
        display: block;
        margin: 5px 0;
      }
     }
    .navigation{
      display:block;
      ul{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align: center;
        li{
          width:100%;
          display:block;
          background:orange;
          margin:0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a codepen or plucker because the css is not complete and does not reproduce your error

Comment: Try and use the "top" and "left" property to move it there

Comment: @Felnyr its because you've used `float:right` for `header .menu` and haven't `clear` the `float` viz why first-child is acting weird.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Thank's thats solved the problem. I added clear: right to `li` element and it worked.